# How do I define all table captions on my website as anchors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, caption

I have a Jekyll-powered GitHub pages website on which, I'd like to hyperlink to where in my posts my tables are and at the moment the only way I know how to do this is by placing a heading immediately before the table. This in turn allows me to hyperlink to the heading that is immediately before the table. For example, https://fusion809.github.io/2015/12/27/comparison-of-free-operating-systems/#programming-languages links to the "Programming Languages" heading in my "A Comparison of Free Operating Systems" post, which is close to, but not immediately before my table entitled "Table 1: A Comparison of Common Programming Languages". Is there a way I can make all table captions (defined with the `<caption>` tag between `<table>` and `</table>` tags) anchors by modifying my website's JavaScript? My table names (or captions) are usually quite long, so if it is possible to use a counter for each, giving them each a number according to their position in my post and then using that for the hyperlink? For example, for the aforementioned post my first table would have the URL https://fusion809.github.io/2015/12/27/comparison-of-free-operating-systems/#table1.

Please try to simplify your answer into simple actions like exactly what I need to add to my website's JavaScript, CSS or HTML as my programming/markup knowledge is in its infancy and hence if you through me in the deep end odds are I'll drown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anchors or other additional tags -- any `id` in the document can be linked to via `http://example.com/mypage#someid`

Assuming the caption text is unique, you can loop through each one and give it an `id` based on its text (after removing non-alphanumeric characters). I've prefixed each `id` with "table-", and lowercased them as well.

In this example, you'd end up with `#table-one`, `#table-two` and `#table-threefour` links available:

```js
$('caption').each(
  function() {
    var cap = this;

    var text = $(cap).text();

    // just a-z, 0-9, - and _
    var id = text.replace(/[^a-z0-9\-\_]/g, '').toLowerCase();

    cap.id = "table-" + id;
  }
);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <caption>one</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <caption>Two</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <caption>three four</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If the captions are *not* unique, you can use a counter and just give them `id`s like `#table1`, `#table2`, etc.

```
var counter = 0;

$('caption').each(
  function() {
    ++counter;
    this.id = 'table-' + counter;
  }
);
```

Comment: Could you show me how to use the counter? It's not that the captions aren't unique it's just that they're long and having to type their full name could get irritating. So instead is it possible to give them all numerical ids. Like `#table1`, `#table2`, *etc.* like in your final example? I'll edit my question to make any revision ya make more appropriate any answer. Sorry, I should have been clear from the beginning.

Comment: I just gave that a try (the counter JS code), it does not seem to be working... See, for example, https://fusion809.github.io/2015/12/27/comparison-of-free-operating-systems/#table1.

Comment: You're running the script too soon - the tables don't exist yet. You need to run it within a `document.ready()` or `window.load` block. See [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), among many other places, for information and examples on that.

Comment: And note that the script uses `table-` as the prefix, not just `table`. You can, of course, change that.